# Is it safe for pets (dog specifically) to eat moldy cheese

Tags: dogs, diet, safety

Title says it all. I have seen my dog eat other things (rabbits, unknown items, etc.) that had been laying around for days. I would try to prevent that, but she has a much better nose than I do. This question is specifically about cheese (cheddar, jack, colby, etc.) that has gone moldy in my fridge.

Comment: Related question: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/can-i-feed-a-dog-cooked-meat-or-fish-that-is-a-week-old

Comment: I have done it without noticeable harm, but I would not recommend it after reading warnings such as this: https://www.petmd.com/dog/conditions/neurological/c_dg_fungi_poisoning

Answer (score 4):

Dogs have a digestive system that is better able to deal with gnarly foods, like half-rotten meat, than our own. This is my opinion, but I would be more worried about the fact that it is cheese, than that it is moldy. Dogs do not handle lactose very well and it can cause them to have horrible gas and constipation. I wouldn't think your dog would necessarily get sick from the mold, but more from the cheese itself. The stomach acid should get rid of the mold spores depending on the species of mold. We eat blue cheese, which is moldy...